# File Upload : Listing previously uploaded files in Edit mode

Tags: javascript, html, angular, file-upload, primeng

I use [PrimeNG File Upload](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/fileupload) in my Angular 6 project and upload files to a master record without any problem. On the other hand, when I edit this master record, I also let users to remove previously added files and add new files by using PrimeNG File Upload.

I think it is good idea to list previously added files (retrieving from Database) of the record as a list item outside of File Upload and display Delete icon right sides of each one. **But** if there is a possibility to display these  previously added files on PrimeNG File Upload, I would like to use File Upload to list them besides adding new ones. So, my questions:

**1)** Is it possible to use PrimeNG File Upload for such an Edit Scenario and list files (from Database) on it?

**2)** Is it weird to list previously added files on File Upload element instead of HTML on the popup windows in Edit mode?

Any help would be appreciated.